# If Humans Could Run Really Fast Could They Get Speeding Tickets?

Tags: humans

Could Humans get Speeding Tickets for going over posted roadway speed limits if they were running faster than those limits? If they did get ticketed would they also get ticketed for being uninsured and not being registered?

Comment: I am voting to close this because it is off topic for this site, especially considering it is simply about existing law in an unspecified country. In the US, no and no. Because those are limits on vehicles, not people.

Comment: Why not? Speeding tickets come from being dangerous to society, and not from having wheels. A human[oid] running fast enough could be dangerous in your setting...

Comment: @Dallaylaen You'd have to ask US lawmakers for the specifics, but the general answer is that laws prohibit things the lawmakers believe to be problems, and people-running-faster-than-cars isn't a real problem in most places.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon - Not true. I've gotten speeding tickets for exceeding 55 mph on my bicycle going down mountain passes in Colorado before. I've had fellow runners get warned for exceeding 10mph on a multi use trail with that limit on it.

Comment: @JohnP Warnings, not tickets. And if they did I'd seriously question what is happening to my country. I don't think it is legal to regulate how fast people can go. It is unconstitutional, in any case. (Hooray tenth amendment!)  And bikes are a kind of vehicle, so that is not running.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon - Don't nitpick. Warning just means the officer was feeling nice. And most multi use trails have low speed limits to accommodate walkers, strollers, pets on leashes, etc. A fast moving object on a narrow path is a hazard, whether it's a person, a bicycle, or larger. And if a municipality can have laws stating it's illegal to dance in certain counties in outdoor venues (Yes, that is an actual local law), they can certainly regulate speed limits on a multi use path.

Comment: @user867 Sure people-running-faster-than-cars are not a problem in our present world. But this is worldbuilding, and super-fast human[oid]s are mentioned explicitly in the topic. Should a drug that allows running at car speed be invented, the law will adjust quickly.

Answer (score 1):

> Could Humans get Speeding Tickets for going over posted roadway speed limits if they were running faster than those limits?
>
> If they did get ticketed would they also get ticketed for being uninsured and not being registered?

No and no. All of these laws apply to motor vehicles, and only to motor vehicles. Likewise, these humans wouldn't be fined for *driving* without a licence, or driving while under the influence of alcohol.

They'd get tickets for jaywalking instead. :P

Comment: Bicycles can get speeding tickets.  They're acting like a vehicle, the lack of a motor is irrelevant.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Bicycles are treated as vehicles because most US states have laws putting bicycles under the same traffic rules as motor vehicles as a legal expedient. Then they patch it up with with exceptions because bicycles and cars are very different. For example, [here's Oregon's](https://goo.gl/srHFBy). Note the definition of "pedestrian" does not contain a max speed. Might the laws be changed? Given the reactionary nature of lawmaking to new things, probably, but as things stand, unless you can find an exception, pedestrians do not have to obey the traffic laws for motor vehicles.

Comment: Electric bicycles create a new grey area between "bicycles" and "motorcycles" similarly to how super-humans would make "pedestrian" a grey area. [Oregon's laws](https://goo.gl/srHFBy) are a good example of how the law will adapt. They added new definitions and clarifications of "electric assisted bicycle" (has a max top speed) vs “electric personal assistive mobility device" (ie. Segway) vs "moped", and so on... I'd imagine "pedestrian" would also be clarified possibly with the addition of "super-human pedestrian" defined as someone moving over X MPH with new rules.